# Set item into array in jQuery and passing in to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, parsing, yii2

I'm using dual listbox in yii2 for eliminate imported Excel header, and while the header was selected I put it into an array `$baru` in dual listbox jquery code using array `push` method.

Here's the code in ***jquery***:

```
dualListbox.elements.select1.find('option:selected').each(function(index, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        var baru = new array();
        if (!$item.data('filtered1')) {
            changeSelectionState(dualListbox, $item.data('original-index'), true);
            if($item.data === 'original-index'){
                baru.push($item);
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know yet if the method works fine or not, if it's fine I want to send the `$baru` into php code for next view process.

Is my code correct? and how to send jquery array to php code?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot pass js array to PHP. You can encode the js array as json and send to PHP through ajax.

Comment: @Naga I've tried, but php can't get the array, and get Warning while use $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to HTTP GET the next page (not changing any state on the server; just returning the next page/view):

```
window.location.href = '/page/next?' + $.param(baru);
```

Comment: I didn't understand, can you describe?